# One-line messages from squashed commits in git merge

Tags: git, merge

When I do:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --squash my-feature-branch && git commit -m ""
```

the resulting commit message is very wordy, containing the complete message from each squashed commit:

```
Squashed commit of the following:

commit ...
Author: ...
Date: ...

    Commit message from the latest squashed commit 

commit ...
Author: ...
Date: ...

    Commit message from the second-latest squashed commit 

    That is, the whole multi-line message unabridged.

...
```

How do I get a commit message that

- contains just the first line of the message of each squashed commit
- without the commit header (commit hash, author, date)?

I.e. like the output of `git log --oneline` but without the commit hashes.

Giving the `--log` option to `git merge` doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Usually `git merge --log --no-commit...` works for me just fine

Comment: @user3159253 That's an ordinary merge and creates a separate commit for each commit merged in from the feature branch. I'm trying to do a squash commit that turns many commits from the feature branch into one commit in the master branch. (The commit _message_ of this resulting commit should be a summary of the commit messages of the source commits. But instead it's a full log of those commits, contrary to what the `git merge` documentation claims.)

Answer (score 0):

This bit of shell works, but it's not pretty:

```sh
b=my-feature-branch
git merge --squash "$b"
git commit -m "$(git log --reverse --format='- %s' .."$b")"
```

Squashed commits are listed from earliest to latest (i.e. naturally in the order they were made) and prefixed with dashes.

I'm not sure how this copes with merge conflicts.

Comment: According to the source code (git 2.8.x), `--log` uses the `%s` directive when formatting commit messages, so simply using `--log` *should* have the same effect as your more-manual solution (except that `--log` and `merge.log` default to maxing out at 30 commits).  Note that all of these simply pre-fill-in the message-file; using an explicit `-m` will ignore the pre-filled-in file in favor of your own arguments.  Since squash "merge" does not commit, if you've been providing some `-m` options, that might explain why `--log` is behaving oddly for you.  Otherwise, well, I have no idea ;-)